# gson and json deserializing

Tags: java, json, gson

This is the json encoding my php echos:

```
{"detail1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},"detail2":["elementone","elementtwo","elementthree"],"detail3":["element1","element2","element3"]}
```

The gson commands i use in the application are:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ParseActivity.parsedata = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken < HashMap < String , Object>>(){}.getType());
```

But gson is giving a jsonparseexception and is not able to parse, parsedata is a static variable of the same type.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be more explicit in the returned type. The field `detail1` is a `Map<String, String>` and other fields are `List<String>`. You need to create a wrapper class (a Javabean) with exactly those fields:

```
public class Details {
    private Map<String, String> detail1;
    private List<String> detail2;
    private List<String> detail3;

    // Add/generate getters/setters.
}
```

so that you can use it as follows:

```
Details details = new Gson().fromJson(result, Details.class);
```

Alternatively, you can let Gson convert it to a `JsonElement` tree so that you can traverse it manually:

```
JsonElement details = new Gson().toJsonTree(result);
```